# Adjusting values in an R dataframe based on another column in the frame

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I'm working with some camera trap data, and some of the cameras are in different time zones and/or the cameras' internal times were incorrect. I have a dataframe with names and timestamps for each of the media files, as well as the time zone the camera was set to and how much the media files' timestamps need to be adjusted. I'm not sure how to adjust the values, though -- everything I've been able to look up so far is for replacing entire values rather than adjusting them. What functions should I be using to add or subtract the time-adjust-duration values from the media-file-date values?

I'm currently using `tidyr`, `dplyr`, and `lubridate` so ideally working with those packages and base would be best.

The dataframe basically looks like this:

| camera-event | time-zone | time-adjust-direction | time-adjust-value | media-file-name | media-file-date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| site_date | UTC -7 | positive | 0000:00:00 00:10:00 | 08100001.JPG | 2021:08:10 06:48:00 |
| site_date | UTC -7 | positive | 0000:00:00 00:10:00 | 08100002.JPG | 2021:08:10 06:59:40 |
| site_date | UTC -6 | negative | 0000:00:00 00:25:00 | 11300050.JPG | 2020:11:30 12:13:05 |
| site_date | UTC -7 | none | 0000:00:00 00:00:00 | 07110154.JPG | 2021:07:11 09:10:00 |

Comment: If you are willing to use a different package, you could use `data.table` to edit in place (by reference).

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (instead of a table as shown here). One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 0):

**dplyr** does not support in-place adjustment. The way you adjust the values of a variable is by replacing them, in other words doing your calculation of interest and then overwriting your original variable, typically using `mutate()`.

In this context, it would be something like

```r
library(dplyr)
dat <- dat %>%
    mutate(`media-file-date` = `media-file-date` - time_adjustment_variable)
```

In the case of your data, I don't think those `0000:00:00 00:10:00` values will be parsed as you want. Assuming they're all less than one day in length you probably want to convert them to HMS first before subtracting them off. Take just the HMS part (the last "word" in your data) and convert to HMS using **lubridate**. You can use `case_when()` to figure out whether you want to add or subtract:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)
dat <- dat %>%
    mutate(adjust_hms = hms(word(`time-adjust-value`, -1))) %>%
    mutate(`media-file-date` = case_when(
        `time-adjust-direction` == 'positive' ~ `media-file-date` + adjust_hms,
        `time-adjust-direction` == 'negative' ~ `media-file-date` - adjust_hms,
        TRUE ~ `media-file-date` # don't adjust the 'none's or anything else
    ))
```